# My program runs fine in debugger but doesnt in release

Tags: c

The point is, I was really trying to search an answer for it but no one had something like my problem. I have a function which finds an item

```
const char *FindItem(int id) {
    FILE *f1;
    f1 = fopen("Items.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    char s1[256];
    while (1) {
        fscanf(f1, "%i", &i);
        if (i == id) {
            fgetc(f1);
            fgets(s1, 256, f1);
            fclose(f1);
            return s1;
        }
        fgets(s1, 256, f1);
    }
}
```

And in `main` I have written

```
int main() {
    printf("%s", FindItem(2));
}
```

In debugger it shows what it is supposed to show but in release mode it shows 2 same random characters `r?`. Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Your function is missing a `return` -> undefined behavior

Comment: ... and even if there was a `return s1`, it would be undefined behavior as well (due to returning the address of a local).

Comment: *Everybody* has this problem at one stage or another. The remedis are, in no particular order: 1. Update to the latest stable compiler version 2. Enable compiler warnings and treat them as errors 3. Use run-time checkers like valgrind, libasan, libubsan.

Comment: It has return but thanks guys i can now try to find a solution (when i know what the problem is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const char * FindItem(int id)
```

returns a pointer to `char`.

```
  return s1;
```

returns from the function to the caller the address of the 1st element of `s1`.

Still, the moment the function `FindItem()` has return `s1` is gone, as it only lived on the function's local stack, existed for the live time of `FindItem()` only.

So

```
  printf("%s", FindItem( ...
```

tries to print data pointed to by what `FindItem()` returned, although the data is gone, as the function returned already.

To fix this, defined the buffer to read into on the caller side and pass the address of its 1st element to the function:

```
char * FindItem(char * s1, int id)
{
    FILE *f1;
    f1 = fopen("Items.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;

    while(1)
    {
      ...


int main(void)
{
  char s1[256];
  printf("%s", FindItem(s1, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not test if `fopen()` succeeded at opening the file. You have undefined behavior if `Items.txt` cannot be open.
- you return a pointer to a local array `s1`. Accessing this object after the function returns has undefined behavior, as you observe. Undefined behavior may be the actual expected behavior or anything else... it may change depending on the execution environment (debug vs production) or or for no reason whatsoever.
- you do not test the return value of `fscanf()`: the loop will go on forever if the number cannot be found in the file.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *FindItem(char *dest, int id) {
    FILE *f1;
    int i, c;

    f1 = fopen("Items.txt", "r");
    if (f1 == NULL)
        return NULL;

    while (fscanf(f1, "%i", &i) == 1) {
        if (i == id) {
            if ((c = fgetc(f1)) == EOF || c == '\n' || fgets(dest, 256, f1) == NULL) {
                *dest = '\0';
            }
            fclose(f1);
            return dest;
        }
        if (fgets(dest, 256, f1) == NULL)
            break;
    }
    fclose(f1);
    return NULL;  /* not found */
}

int main(void) {
    char s1[256];
    if (FindItem(s1, 2)) {
        printf("%s", s1);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("not found\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```